# Opening links within apps causes bad switch to Chrome in Nougat

Tags: chrome-for-android, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7

Running the latest Nougat beta on Sprint Galaxy S7.

Whenever I open a weblink within an app (such as reddit, Google Search/Now, Gmail) the link opens within the app, but as soon as it's done loading my phone switches to Chrome -- but does *not* open the link in Chrome.

To see the page, I have to switch back to the original app.

Is there a fix for this? I tried clearing Chrome defaults, disabling/re-enabling Chrome, uninstalling Chrome updates. No dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your "Android System WebView" application.

It may be happening because of the confusion to an app of choosing which web view app or you can say service to use...

I have CyanogenMod 14.1 which is based on Nougat. There's this option in 
Settings -> Developer Options -> WebView implementation

[image: WebView implementation dialog]

Comment: Aha ... mine is called "Android System WebView", at version 54.0.2840.85. In my Dev Options I only have the "Chrome Stable" option. But I am not rooted so I don't see how I can update this.

Comment: OK, I updated via Play Store to version 55.0.2883.91 but it's marked as "disabled" and I can't enable. Weird.

Comment: Installing Chrome Beta & disabling regular version seems to have fixed it for now. Apparently WebView is deprecated in Nougat.

Comment: [Related article](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview) regarding "Chrome as WebView", although it's focused more for developer.